# Social media get bulk link statistics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, linkedin-api

Is there a way to get link statistics for multiple URLs using only one GET request?

Something along the lines of https://graph.facebook.com?links=[link1,link2,link3]

I know how to get single link stats

Facebook

```
https://graph.facebook.com?id=mylink
```

Twitter

```
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=mylink
```

Linkedin

```
https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=json&url=mylink
```

Comment: For Facebook: `https://graph.facebook.com?ids=url1,url2,url3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. Furthermore, Twitter will be removing their link statistics API call in November - see https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform